# getImageSize() fails to work

Tags: php, gd

I have the following code below and I do not understand why I cannot retrieve the width and height of an image file.

```
 <?php

 $myImage = 'http://www.example.com/storage/james.JPG';


 $imageSize = getimagesize($myImage); // 'line 6'

 $imageWidth = $imageSize[0];
 $imageHeight = $imageSize[1];

 echo 'width: '.$imageWidth.'<br />';  // returns blank
 echo 'height'.$imageHeight.'<br />'; // returns blank


 ?>
 <img src="http://www.example.com/storage/james.JPG"> // image is disaplyed.
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
 getimagesize(thanh.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in     /home/lifescieco/public_html/newboston_image.php on line 6
```

Comment: *No such file or directory* says all to fix your error .... give getimagesize() the correct file link, best way is always use absolute paths

Comment: if `storage` directory is under public_html, try giving `$myImage = "http://domain.com/storage/james.JPG"; `

Comment: I have tried this and i am getting 'failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/myDomain/public_html/myImageFile.php on line 6'

Comment: Also keep in mind that some operating systems are case-sensitive with filenames.

Comment: Is the file on your server, or are you trying to access an image on a different host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess the actual source of your problem, as your information are kind of limited. However, here are some checks you could perform:

- Is the path correct?
- Is the file accessible within the operating scope and for the PHP user?
- Is the filename correct? Also keep in mind that some operating systems are case-sensitive.
- If the file lays on a remote computer: Is [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.allow-url-fopen) set to `1` (on)? In Windows versions prior to PHP 4.3.0, also take in mind that many functions (including GD and image functions) do not support remote file access. See  [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/filesystem.configuration#ini.allow-url-fopen) for more information.